# Обязательное для заполнения поле в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется такой код контроллера

```
public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);
        return view('cars_add',[
            'validator' => $validator
        ]);
    }
```

и такой html

```
    <div class="item">
        <label>Заголовок</label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <?php if($errors->has('title')): ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $errors->first('title'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Почему то информация об ошибке при пустом поле не выходит, в чем проблема?

Comment: Какая версия Laravel? В вопросе укажите

Answer (score 2):

Вы не передаете ошибки в темплейт. Вот пример работающего валидатора. 
[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

p.s прошу обратить внимание что валидатор менялся на протяжении версий. Пример к 5.2

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new blog post.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что вы передаете в шаблон переменную `$validator`, а не `$errors` в этом участке кода:

> ```
> return view('cars_add',[
>     'validator' => $validator
> ]);
> ```

Исправьте объявление переменной:

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);
    return view('cars_add',[
        'errors' => $validator
    ]);
}
```